# SQLite delete from table where condition is of boolean type

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am trying to run this query without success :

```
DataModule1.UniQuery5.Close;
DataModule1.UniQuery5.SQL.Clear;
DataModule1.UniQuery5.SQL.Text:='delete from mytable where job_done = "1"';
DataModule1.UniQuery5.ExecSQL;
```

Job_done is a boolean field.
Since SQLite has only 2 conditions for true/false (0 or 1), I am failing to understand why nothing gets deleted. Can you help me ?

Comment: job_done isn't a boolean field as SQLite doesn't have a boolean data type and SQLite fields only have recommended types. They're something like dynamic types and there's nothing to stop you from putting any data you want into any field (although it will try to convert it to the recommended field type if possible). At least on the SQLite end I had no problem creating a table with an integer job_done field and running a query that deletes any record with a text 1 in the job_done field (SQLite auto-converted the value and deleted the record successfully). Are you sure about the values in job_done

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
delete from mytable where job_done = 1;
```

without quotes

Comment: @user3777264 Then there's something other than 1 or 0 in the job_done field. Time to inspect the data. SQLite does not have fixed field data types unlike almost all other SQL databases.

Comment: strange thing... If I use 'delete from mytable where job_done = 0';then unchecked items get deleted.Just the way they should. Just cant make the '1' work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sqlite does not have boolean type fields. So I changed the type to wideinteger.Now unchecked marks to '0' and checked to '-1'. Now,this way, everything works.